# Configure EJS view engine options - Express framework

Tags: node.js, ejs

How can I configure the open/close tags ([see "Custom Tags" in the documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs)) in the EJS view engine, which is included in the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/)?

Answer (score 4):

Found this in the documentation, under http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering

```
app.set('view options', {
    open: '{{',
    close: '}}'
});
```

Comment: This does not work anymore for express >= 3.0