# changing type of code wrapper for express + node.js + ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In client side ejs I use `[% code %]` instead of `<% code %>` to mark ejs code, but I would like to do the same on the server side with express.  On the client side I would do something like `var template = new EJS({text: template_src, type:'['});`

Here is my node code:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.register('.html', require('ejs'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html', { title: 'My Site' });
});
```

Where do you set the "type" paramater so I can change this option

Comment: Seems like the question already exists.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532404/configure-ejs-view-engine-options-express-framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the EJS github page:](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs)

> Custom tags can also be applied globally:

```
var ejs = require('ejs'); ejs.open = '{{'; ejs.close = '}}';
```

The only thing you need to do it copy these lines at the beginning of your Express app and that's that - the change is applied globally (change the open and close tag to whatever you want).

**Update for most recent version as of July 20, 2016**

As of most recent versions of EJS, it is not possible to use custom tags anymore (see https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/55 ). All you can do is change delimiters from default `%` to others ( `delimiter` option ). 
There are talks about re-enabling this. See https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/88 and https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/115

Answer (score 6):

If you use express:

```
app.set('view options', {
    open: '{{',
    close: '}}'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[ejs v2.*](http://ejs.co/) use a different option:

```
var ejs = require('ejs'),
users = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];

// Just one template
ejs.render('<?= users.join(" | "); ?>', {users: users},
    {delimiter: '?'});
// => 'geddy | neil | alex'

// Or globally
ejs.delimiter = '$';
ejs.render('<$= users.join(" | "); $>', {users: users});
// => 'geddy | neil | alex'
```

You can't replace the `<` and `>` character.