# Express js set view template options

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

In Express.js application to register template engine `ejs` you just add one line

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

How to specify additional options supported by the ejs https://github.com/mde/ejs#options (e.g. I want `rmWhitespace: true`) so that every `res.render()` would use them?

UPDATE:
current set up:

```
...
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.locals.rmWhitespace = true;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('root', { name: 'Test' });
});
```

and in `./views/root.ejs'

```
<html>
<body>
    Hello, <%= name -%>
    <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure EJS view engine options - Express framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532404/configure-ejs-view-engine-options-express-framework)

Comment: @laggingreflex it doesn't work

Comment: try `app.locals.rmWhitespace = true`

Comment: @laggingreflex unfortunately this doesn't work too, please see update for my current code. Thanks!

Comment: ok try `app.locals.options.rmWhitespace = true`

Comment: @laggingreflex I had to set `app.locals.options = {};` first but still no luck

Comment: @laggingreflex I tried your suggestion on another parameter `app.locals.delimiter = '?'` and it worked. So the problem seems to be that either `ejs` doesn't support `rmWhitespace` or for some reason it didn't find any "safe" whitespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original syntax works now:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.locals.rmWhitespace = true;
```

It didn't work at the time you asked your question, due to a bug which was fixed in v2.3.4: https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/ea0fa32e27a13b9b77970b312699ff117aa56e59

Without this fix in place, `rmWhitespace` was not recognized as an "option", and therefore wasn't yanked out of `data` and into `opts` by the [`cbOptsInData`](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/ea0fa32e27a13b9b77970b312699ff117aa56e59/lib/ejs.js#L251) method.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation: `ejs.render(str, data, options);`

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('root', { name: 'Test' }, rmWhitespace);
});
```

http://ejs.co/

Comment: `res.render` =/= `ejs.render`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using swig, an alternative to ejs.
I think you can directly require ejs and set its options. For example :

```
var ejs = require('ejs');    

...
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
ejs.rmWhitespace = true;
...
```

Comment: Sorry ! Maybe you can try to set the view engine after setting ejs.rmWhitespace

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
 res.locals.rmWhitespace = true;
 next();
});
```

setup locals as `res.locals`

set docs here [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals)

Answer (score 0):

[Only some EJS options](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/main/lib/ejs.js#L61-L62) get passed from EJS via locals (no matter given on `render` or via `app.locals`). To set other options, set the template engine call as [described here](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express#custom-render-function):

```js
let ejsOptions = { delimiter: '?' }
app.engine('ejs', (path, data, cb) => {
  ejs.renderFile(path, data, ejsOptions, cb)
})
```